# how to dynamically define workflow in Apache Oozie?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm new to Apache Oozie and as far as I understood the workflow/cordinator jobs must be pre-defined in an xml files. However, in my problem I need to dynamically define the workflow, that is depending on the input files I might have extra actions in my workflow. Is there any way to programmatically do that?

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with Mzf's response, but want to add something to also answer jamiet's question and create a more general answer.
If it is the case that it makes sense to split your workflow into multiple flows/cases then a Decision Control Node is the way to go.

Sometimes it is necessary however - like jamiet asked in the comments - that you want to call a workflow/action for an iteration over a collection. This means that each time you run a workflow the possible length of the workflow can vary from only 1 action to 100 depending on the collection. This is not something you can represent using simple decision control nodes. One of my use cases is the generation of one workflow to do the sqoop import for each of the table/database pairs present in a config file.

My solution for this problem is to have 1 workflow call a custom script possibly with some parameters. This script then builds the workflow.xml file of the 'dynamic workflow' containing the actions that correspond to your collection. Once the workflow.xml has been built, the script calls `oozie job` with a job.properties files pointing to the newly created workflow.xml.

Comment: I am looking for such a solution to import a previously unknown number of external data sources, i.e., a number of Google sheets via BigQuery. Currently I am doing this using a Bash+Python Script that fetches all data in parallel, thereafter using the `hdfs`, `hive`, and `impala-shell` CLIs to load the acquired data to Hadoop/Hive sequentially. Having real workflow actions for each step would make the process much more transparent, repeatable, and debuggable. Can you add some code to your answer, showng a basic setup to dynamically create the 1 to 100 followup workflows from the main workflow?

Comment: I feel like real code would add to much to my answer and would lose some of the generality. So my suggestion is to create code which is able to dynamically build a workflow.xml file based on certain input. If e.g. you need to have 100 queries you should consider writing a function which outputs a single oozie xml Hive <action>. This function can then be called with the right parameters as many times as you like. In the end you would have a workflow.xml file containing as many actions as you like. This code is able to produce a different workflow.xml each time it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow & coordinator are pre-defined files - that doesn't mean that that you can't control the workflow actions.

If you have several cases/flows in your workflow , you can add [Decision Control Node](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node) to control the flow in your workflow.

For example let say that you say if I have input A it will do ActionA_1,ActionA_2 and for input case B will do ActionB_1, ActionB_2, use  [Decision Control Node](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.1.4_Decision_Control_Node) choose execution path to follow

Comment: What if I have to do something like iterating over a collection and calling a workflow for each iterated value? Is that possible? (And yes, I totally accept that this is antithetical to the whole notion of Oozie workflows being DAGs, but sometimes needs must)